# Limit data selection isn't working for my pagination

Tags: php

I have this code, but when I put the LIMIT data selection with the variables it won't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM structure
        WHERE row1 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row2 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row3 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row4 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row5 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row6 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "% '
        LIMIT {$variable} , {$variable2}";
```

But if I put the same code, but changing the LIMIT data selection to numbers it will work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM structure WHERE row1   LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row2 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row3 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row4 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row5 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row6 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."% ' LIMIT 0 , 5 ";
```

I need to use variables, since it won't be always constant.

**EDIT**: here is my entire code:

```
$record_per_page = 5;
if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $page = $_POST['query'];
    $start_from = ($page - 1) * $record_per_page;
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM structure
              WHERE row1 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
              OR row2 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
              LIMIT $start_from , $record_per_page";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= ' ';
        }
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: use variable directly there:- `$sql = "SELECT * FROM structure WHERE row1   LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row2 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row3 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row4 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row5 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."%' OR row6 LIKE'%".$_POST["query"]."% ' LIMIT $variable1 , $variable2";`

Comment: Check that the two variables hold what your expecting ($variable1 & 2)

Comment: yes they contain the pagination : $page = $_POST['query'];
 $start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page;

Comment: what does this line of Your code: `$page = $_POST['query'];`???

Comment: With this I wanted to get what the ajax function is getting from the search, and know how many "pages" contais the result

Comment: in this line: `$start_from = ($page - 1) * $record_per_page;` You subtracted `1` from `$page`, when Your `$page` variable is string???

Comment: yes, i wanted to put ($_POST['query']), to get the number of pages that the result has. So imagine Im search for "text" and text has 100 entries in my data base, and the record per page is 5. so that will be 20 pages of result ( 100 / 5).

Comment: ok if `$_POST['query']` is number of entries, then what is that: `              WHERE row1 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
              OR row2 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'`???

Comment: they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough rep to comment, sry.
First read this if you're not already using PDO, especially the prepared statements section. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Next, select the columns you actually need, not a lazy select *.
Also, could you post some your table definition? Curious to see what it is like.

And finally:

```
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM structure
WHERE row1 LIKE
    OR row2 LIKE ? 
    OR row3 LIKE ?
    OR row4 LIKE ?
    OR row5 LIKE ?
    OR row6 LIKE ?
LIMIT " . $variable1 . " , " . $variable2;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute( ); //insert your parameters here
```

This should get you on your way =)

Comment: Hello, what are the PDO used for?

Comment: With the SELECT* I have selected all the rows i had in my table wich are as many as I show in the example

Comment: PDO allows you to use prepared statements. Including user input directly into your query is a massive security risk. As far as doing `select *` is concerned, imagine you change the table later on to add columns, they will now automatically be included in that query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need curly braces in `LIMIT`:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM structure
        WHERE row1 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row2 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row3 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row4 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row5 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row6 LIKE'%" . $_POST["query"] . "% '
        LIMIT " . $start_from. " , " . $record_per_page. "";
```

**EDIT:**
print Your `$variable` & `$variable2` for sure...

Change this line: `$start_from = ($page - 1) * $record_per_page;`

Comment: hi, i tried not inserting curly braces but It still doen't work

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
 
 
  ';
 }

 }  

 echo $output;  




}

else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

}

?>

Comment: before the $sql variable

Comment: these variables has value?

Comment: $page = $_POST['query'];
 $start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page;

Comment: Dear friend, please if You can add You entire code!

Comment: $record_per_page = 5;  
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
 $page = $_POST['query'];
 $start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page; 
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM structure
        WHERE row1 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
        OR row2 LIKE '%" . $_POST["query"] . "%'
       LIMIT {$start_from} , {$record_per_page}";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {  $output .= '   '; }
 echo $output;